# InvalidAppConfigError: Duplicate module: my-service

Tags: google-app-engine, go, dev-appserver

My computer (`Windows 10`) hosting my VM (`Ubuntu 16.04`) restarted last night (because Windows is a jerk) and now I can't seem to run my service locally. This was running fine yesterday and I haven't changed a single line of code. Only thing that happened was the reboot.

I am running `dev_appserver.py ./ app.yaml`.

My `app.yaml` file:

```
runtime: go
api_version: go1
service: my-service

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: _go_app

#[START env_variables]
env_variables:
 GCLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET: my-cloud-bucket
#[END env_variables]
```

and the error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 103, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 97, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 350, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 338, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 94, in start
    env_variables=parsed_env_variables)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 953, in __init__
    module.module_name)
google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.errors.InvalidAppConfigError: Duplicate >module: my-service
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to specify **both** the application directory (`./` in your case) **and** the `app.yaml` simultaneously. From [Running the local development server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/tools/using-local-server#running_the_local_development_server):

> Specify the directory path to your app, for example:
>
> ```
> dev_appserver.py [PATH_TO_YOUR_APP]
> ```
>
> Alternatively, you can specify the configuration file of a specific
>   service, for example:
>
> ```
> dev_appserver.py app.yaml
> ```

Most likely the server detects the `app.yaml` from the directory specification and then gets it again from the `app.yaml` specification, leading to the duplicate service error.

I'd simply drop the `./` directory specification from the command line (I'd rather not rely on the auto-detection, which can fail miserably for multi-service apps).

Comment: Oh my how silly I am. The restart didn't save my user history so I was typing in the command from memory (and doing a bad job of it apparently!) Thanks, you just saved me a huge headache.